# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, json, resttemplate

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestResult {
private Map<String, String> datas;
>
......}
```

when I use RestTemplate as follows I got error message as title

```
TestResult result= restTemplate.postForObject(AppConstants.URL +Secure/View/getTest",request, TestResult.class);
```

when I use jmeter try got data is correct,but falue at android (use RestTemplate)
please help me how to fix it, thanks!

```
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865): 17:08:27.570 pool-12-thread-1 An exception occured during request network execution :Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance   of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):  at [Source: libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream@41b46428; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: model.vo.TestResult["datas"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):  at [Source: libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream@41b46428; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: model.vo.TestResult["datas"])
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865): org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):  at [Source: libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream@41b46428; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: model.vo.TestResult["datas"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):  at [Source: libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream@41b46428; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: model.vo.TestResult["datas"])
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:125)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:76)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:317)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at service.TestRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(TestRequest.java:73)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at service.TestRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(TestRequest.java:1)
10-17 17:08:27.571: E//RequestProcessor.java:250(16865):    at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:27)
```

Comment: post the whole stack trace

Comment: can you show a sample response too?

Answer (score 0):

Check the raw response, try hitting that url in the browser or rest client to see what is getting returned.

> Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance   of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
>
> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
> chain: model.vo.TestResult["datas"])

Hard to determine with just this amount of info. It looks like the json response contained an array object but the java bean field is a string.